# Override system-wide shortcut for application-specific shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

Is there a way to give a keyboard shortcut defined in an application precedence over a system-wide shortcut with the same key binding?

**Desired behaviour:**
When *some keys* are pressed, check if the focussed application wants to do anything (and if so, do it). If not, check if there is a system shortcut for *some keys* and then do that.

**What currently happens:**
I have <kbd>F11</kbd> set as 'toggle fullscreen' in the settings menu for keyboard shortcuts. In Chrome <kbd>F11</kbd> should activate Chrome's own fullscreen mode, but instead is overridden by the system-wide shortcut, i.e. Chrome becomes fullscreen (GNOME panel and title bar vanish) but does not enter Chrome's fullscreen mode (where the tabs, address bar and bookmarks bar also vanish).

(Side note: Firefox does not have the same problem, but this seems to be because FF fullscreen is the same as/is triggered by the window manager fullscreen)

Comment: The first question that comes to my mind; what talks to the OS about key presses, the application, or X / Wayland? It seems to me that the X will handle a key press, and mangle it if required, before passing it to the window your application is waiting for you on. The second question is how would X know if the application has changed state, and how would it know if a change occurred directly because of a keypress?  I'd be inclined to go out on a limb and say that you are out of luck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This is not exactly what you want, but I've spent too much time on this not to post it and maybe someone else can use it.*

**I got as far as Ctrl + F11 is fullscreen everywhere but Chromium where it is Chromium's fullscreen !**

1. **Train of thought**

---

I thought I might be able to trick the window manager if I use `xdotool` and send the command directly to the chrome window - to no avail.

Then I thought I might be able to change the keyboard shortcut in google chrome, but that seems hardcoded - another dead end.

2. **Which leaves us with this**

---

Install `xdotool` to simulate keyboard presses

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

reconfigure the Ubuntu Keyboard shortcuts to something arbitrary, that we never type but is usable in the script

**Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard**

Scroll down and edit **Toggle fullscreen mode** to `Ctrl + Alt + 1` and then hit the `+` and add a custom keyboard shortcut

[image: keyboard shortcuts - fullscreen]

and then hit the `+` and add a custom keyboard shortcut

[image: dialog of custom shortcut]

edit the script

```
nano /home/user/fullscreen.sh


#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
windowname=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | cut -d "-" -f 2)
if [[ $windowname != *"Chromium"* ]]
then
xdotool keydown Ctrl keydown Alt key 1 keyup Alt keyup Ctrl
else
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Chromium" windowfocus 
sleep 0.2
xdotool key F11
fi
```

make it executeable

```
chmod +x /home/user/fullscreen.sh
```

---

3. **Conclusion**

It seems impossible to trick the windowmanager and smuggle keystroke by, but there are certainly workarounds possible. In this case Google made the fullscreen keyboard shortcut non-configureable, so it falls just short of the mark

Now with **Ctrl + F11** the windowmanager controls the fullscreen behavior except in chromium.

Comment: Think you're right that this is the best we can hope for - shame that Chrome/ium doesn't support custom keyboard shortcuts.

Worth noting: choice of keyboard shortcut matters for this trick! I already had Ctrl+F11 bound to something else. Tried with Shift+Alt+F11, which didn't work. Alt+F11 worked fine though. (I guess it was attempting to do Shift+Ctrl+Alt+F11)